# How can I know the cpu and net bandwidth required for my transaction to be completed?

Tags: transactions, resources

Before pushing an action on blockchain, how do I find out the minimum amount of cpu and net bandwidth required for my transaction to be completed? If there is no way to know such thing, then how do I decide how much EOS do I delegate to my account (I want to minimise the amount of EOS delegated)

Answer (score 2):

CPU bandwidth depends on execution time and net bandwidth depends on the transaction size (bytes). The only way to know is to measure, either on the mainnet or on a similarly-loaded testnet. CPU bandwidth will vary between producers.

Option A:

- Run `cleos get account` and look at the `used` fields under `net bandwidth` and `cpu bandwidth`
- Issue the transaction
- Run `cleos get account` and subtract the fields

Option B:

- Issue the transaction
- Get these fields from the transaction from the block: `cpu_usage_us` and `net_usage_words`

`cleos get account` example:

```
$ cleos get account useraaaaaaaa

net bandwidth: (averaged over 3 days)
     staked:   50335451.0469 SYS           (total stake delegated from account to self)
     delegated:       0.0000 SYS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:               384 bytes
     available:        38.46 Gb   
     limit:            38.46 Gb   

cpu bandwidth: (averaged over 3 days)
     staked:   50335451.0469 SYS           (total stake delegated from account to self)
     delegated:       0.0000 SYS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:             17.05 ms   
     available:        0.676 hr   
     limit:            0.676 hr
```

Comment: The example is for Option A. Could you also provide an example for Option B?

Comment: any documents? like formulas or codes? If my transaction has a big `memo`, does that mean it take more net? or more ram?

Comment: @spartucus big memo should take more net and more cpu but not more ram